# Django: Cleaning SQLite d/b for obsolete apps/models

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm new to Django and wanted to clean some invalid d/b objects that were created as part of some model creation which is no more valid. Is there a script to remove unused d/b objects from SQlite?

Comment: When is a model invalid? Does it mean calling `.full_clean()` on it will raise an error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The apps were deleted manually and so the model but with a left over in SQlite which requires a cleaning. I'm using VS Code and installed the sqlite extension as well but it doesn't help. I did remove the tables after installing sqlite exe but that is again a manual process so looking for some python script to remove obsolete tables.